# Citrus iOS Integration: Invalid signature key

Tags: android, ios, payment, credit-card

I am using citrus Payments for payment using credit card in iOS. I have generated a bill from my server and am creating a CTSBill using merchant transaction id, amount, request signature, merchant access key, return url and notify url. I am then passing this to requestChargePayment method, but I get an error *Invalid signature key*.

```
            let creditCard = CTSElectronicCardUpdate(creditCard: ())
            creditCard.number = "5555555555554444"   //test card
            creditCard.expiryDate = "12/2017" 
            creditCard.scheme = 
            creditCard.ownerName = "Anna"
            creditCard.cvv = 132  //Dummy one 
            let paymentInfo : CTSPaymentDetailUpdate = CTSPaymentDetailUpdate()
            paymentInfo.addCard(creditCard)

            PaymentUtil.sharedInstance.paymentLayer.requestChargePayment(paymentInfo, withContact: self.getContactInfo(), withAddress: self.getAddressInfo(), bill: bill, customParams: nil, returnViewController: self, withCompletionHandler: { (cashRes, error) -> Void in
            //error

            })
```

I get the following error in the block:

> Error Domain=com.citrus.errorDomain Code=383066336 "Invalid signature key" UserInfo=0x16b57490 {NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid signature key}

The same parameters work for android and I have verified the keys I have been using but not sure what am I doing wrong.

Comment: check your key is valid or not

Comment: Cross checked with the android implementation.

Comment: The vanityUrl was incorrect. Thanks.

Comment: @I am not get in your point